# Import mailbox from Mail (with no mail account access) to Gmail

Tags: ios, email, import

On my iPhone on Mail, I have a mailbox from a provider that I no longer have access to (emails were downloaded via POP while I still had access). I don't want to lose those emails. Is there a way I can import them into say Gmail or another provider that I now use from the iPhone?

Comment: Can't you just move them into a folder on Gmail?

Comment: How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Navigate to the mailbox to be migrated
- Tap "Edit" at top right
- Tap "Select all" at top left
- Tap "Move" at bottom center
- Navigate to the target account
- Tap on target folder to have mails moved there